# Using np.memmap to read steam of data

Tags: python, numpy, file-io

I have a very large data file in bytes and when I use `np.memmap` I would run out of resource to read the file and I also cannot use `fp.read`. The solution that I thought of is to stream the file, using the following code,

```
with open(filename, mode='rb') as fp:
    while True:
        chunk = fp.read(1024)
        int_chunk = numpy.fromfile(chunk, dtype=numpy.int16)
        
        if not chunk:
            break
```

However, when I do this I get the following error,

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode btye 0xff in position 68: invalid start byte
```

I'm not sure how can I steam and convert the data at the same time. Any ideas or work around is appreciated!